# Meaning of "material design"

Tags: terminology, google-material-design

I have seen several websites and smartphone apps claim that they employ a "material design".

Is this a lose term, or not? What exactly does this term mean our imply?

Comment: Did you google it by any chance? https://material.google.com/

Comment: Related/possible dupe http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41628/23061

Answer (score 1):

It is a specific perspective from google to make aplications and web design,  focused to give, for example, android developers a consistent way of making the visual style of the app.

Not only the visual style but also the visual feedback from the aplication.

https://material.google.com/