# What is the name of this computer animation art style?

Tags: style-identification

I really like the art style of the following image (single colors, low-detail and hexagons). What is it called so I can learn more about it?

[image]

Comment: Hello Hector! Please edit your question to follow our [style identification guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2931/52050) or your question will likely get closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest **Flat design 2.0**
See this illustration showing Flat design vs Flat design 2.0:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

its  called  Material  Design :)

Comment: This is incorrect. See [What is the difference between “flat style” and “material design”?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/41716/23061)