# What is this type of graphic art design style called?

Tags: style, art

[image]

Hi, can anyone please help me find out what kind of graphic design style this is, and how is it called?

Answer (score 1):

I'd call this **Flat 2.0**, with more than a slight touch of influence from classic 80's vintage ***Nagel***.

Please also see:

[Finding a suggestion or real name for the new illustration style](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114857/finding-a-suggestion-or-real-name-for-the-new-illustration-style)

[What is the correct style that describes the following images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114409/what-is-the-correct-style-that-describes-the-following-images/114410#114410)

[What is the name of this computer animation art style?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87333/what-is-the-name-of-this-computer-animation-art-style/87360#87360)

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knIzu.png) is what came up when I Googled "Nagel bushes" haha