# What do you call this style of illustration I've been seeing quite a lot?

Tags: website-design, illustration, stock-images

There is often organic shape, very minimalist illustration of a person(s).

[image]

I know these are flat vectors, I want to know name of artistic style.

Comment: [Also here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/114409/120647), [and here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/87333/120647)

Comment: they aren't just flat vector? otherwise all mono color icons are flat vectors too. and they aren't the same. This one is more 'organic'

Comment: You could describe it as a flat or 2D curvilinear illustration.  Curvilinear means "made from curved lines", but yes it's still a kind of flat illustration, regardless of the actual shapes themselves. There's no specific one word term for this style of illustration, at least not in English.

Comment: main reason i want to know what they are called is so i can google. while english may not have word for it, google might have already associated certain words with this style in particular.

Comment: right now this is the closes i've come "vector  person illustration 2019 trend web design"

Comment: Instead of looking on google images, try searching stock image websites such as Adobe Stock.  Simply searching [flat vector illustration](https://stock.adobe.com/uk/search/images?filters%5Bcontent_type%3Aphoto%5D=1&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Aillustration%5D=1&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Azip_vector%5D=1&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Aimage%5D=1&k=flat+vector+illustration&order=relevance&price%5B%24%5D=1&safe_search=1&search_page=1&acp=&aco=flat+vector+illustration&limit=100&get_facets=0) will return hundreds of similar images.