# What's this minimalist icon style called?

Tags: icon, style-identification, google-material-design

I've been seeing this "style" of minimalist icon more and more, with that "shadow" on the bottom right. Is there a specific name for this? Thanks.

[image: icon]

Comment: Related question: [What is the difference between “flat style” and “material design”?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41628/23061)

Answer (score 1):

It's modeled after the [Google Material Design](https://design.google.com/resources/?gclid=CMa_nq6gp9MCFYg6gQodoxkF0Q) guidelines.

To me.. it's quickly becoming an overused trend, but then almost all "trends" get overused.

Answer (score 1):

That style of icon design, and specifically the shadow is called “long shadow”. You can find lots of examples on Dribbble and in other places.

- https://dribbble.com/search?q=longshadow
- https://www.behance.net/search?content=projects&sort=appreciations&time=week&search=long%20shadow
- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=long+shadow+icon&t=osx&iar=images&iax=1&ia=images

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for stock imagery, search for "flat + long shadow icon".