# Style identification of flat-ish design with gradients

Tags: interface-design, style-identification

I am looking for a general name or style identification of this type of design. Mainly so I can look for more examples and their common theme.

[[image: enter image description here]]

Click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Ekd.jpg)

More examples can be found on the authors [Behance page](https://www.behance.net/gallery/60563051/iOS-UI-Kit-For-Hotel-Booking).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "flat style" and "material design"?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/what-is-the-difference-between-flat-style-and-material-design)

Comment: This topic is not about what is Material Design or Flat Design! It's about what we are allowed to use in each style! for example, before this I didn't know we are allowed to use gradient in Material Design

Comment: But How could we use the gradients because I can't find any rule to use it in https://material.io/design/color/ reference!

Comment: It's _based_ on the material design guidelines. You are allowed to do whatever you want with; it's just a guide, not hard rules.

Comment: @Luciano I agreed :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we have name for these kind of "flat graphics" images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17350/do-we-have-name-for-these-kind-of-flat-graphics-images)

Answer (score 1):

The "iOS UI Kit For Hotel Booking" appears to be offered on [Creative Market](https://creativemarket.com/RagulBala29/2219656-Complete-UI-Kit-Hotel-Booking-App) and on the designer's [Behance](https://www.behance.net/gallery/60563051/iOS-UI-Kit-For-Hotel-Booking) page (which has a link to the aforementioned CM page.)

Note for future reference, I took your image above and dragged into google images and that led me to the links herein.

Comment: definitely, for its shadows, gradients... it is not flat design, so what is then?

Comment: Hello Danny, welcome to GDSE, we're glad to have you! You can read the introduction in [help] on how to improve your answer and [edit] it accordingly.  Your answer does not really seem to answer the question, it is more like a comment or an edit to the original question. Feel free to contribute to the site by asking more questions or answering questions.

Comment: @PieBie - oh yes, i see now, the OP was looking to see what the style of the design is, not the actual link. Would you like me to delete this answer?

Comment: No worries, thanks for your contribution anyway. You don't necessarily have to delete your answer, if you know the name of the style or have more information you can always [edit] it in.